# Transforming callbacks into promises

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm asking the server for a piece of information in two different ways. Without promises it could work as follows

```
function callback(someData) {
    displaySomeData();
}

request1(user.name, callback);
request2(user.id, callback);
```

Both request may return the needed information<sup>1</sup> and one or both may be fruitless. The `callback` handles missing information properly.

Actually, the two requests are trivially aggregated into a single one like

```
aggregateRequest(user, callback) {
    request1(user.name, callback);
    request2(user.id, callback);
}
```

I'm curious how this can be written with promises.

I know that there's a `$q.all(promises)` which invokes its `then` argument when all promises are fulfilled. I guess I'd need something like `$q.each` which invokes its argument each time one promise gets fulfilled.

Maybe it's a stupid idea to use promises in *this case*... but having a mix of promises and callbacks feels terrible.

---

<sup>1</sup> We can argue that doing it sequentially saves a request in case the first one succeeds. We can also argue that combining the two requests would be more efficient. But let's forget it for now.

## EDIT

Ideally, I'd like to react to both requests, as each might return different pieces data worth combining. I'd really have to invoke the `then` part twice and I'm afraid, it's not something promises were designed for.

I'll probably go for `all`. Or maybe for a modified version of Benjamin Gruenbaum's `any`, where I return the first result only if it's good enough (and otherwise await the second one and combine them).

Comment: So what happens then if one or both calls are fruitless, is a fruitless call a 200 response? continue? make call again?

Comment: @StenMuchow: Fruitless means "server doesn't know". Currently 200 with an empty response `{}`. It's no error and it's cacheable, no sense in retrying.

Comment: Then I have to agree with the response from @ivarni - except I would also add a failure method to the then block.

Comment: Good point about error-handling, that needs to be done by another function rather than inside the callback.

Comment: What is returned by `request1()` and `request2()`?  At least one of the answers assumes Promises but I don't believe this is a safe assumption, and most likely incorrect given that both functions accept a callback parameter.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Yes, I rewrote them to return promises (this was the easy part).

Comment: Ah OK, in that case `request1` and `request2` probably don't need to accept a callback function as a parameter. It is likely (and certainly conventional) that such a function can be applied, at the point of invocation, with a chained `.then()`, eg: `request1(user.name).then(callback)` and `request1(user.id).then(callback)`.

Comment: Add that to Ben G's answer (to generate his `promise1` and `promise2`), and you may then have a solution.

Comment: And you should really return something from `callback` to allow the possibility of further method chaining. eg. function callback(someData) { return displaySomeData(); }. Exactly what is returned depends on your application. At its simplest, you can return `someData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way in `$q` to write a `.any` method that resolves with the method of one promise from several. However, it's perfectly simple to write one.

```
function any(){
    var rejected = 0;
    var d = $q.defer();
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
         arguments[i].then(function(val){ d.resolve(val); }).catch(function(el){
              rejected++;
              if(rejected == arguments.length) d.reject(new Error("All promises rejected"));
         });
    }
    return d.promise();
}

any(promise1,promise2).then(function(value){
      // access the value of the resolved promise (first one) here.
}).catch(function(err){
      // error caught here if the above .then threw, or if all promises rejected
});
```

This works since a promise is an abstraction over a one time operation and resolves only once.

Do **not** revert to callbacks. Callbacks are not throw safe and have problematic error handling, when you mix callbacks and promises in more than one layer, you lose.

Promises are an abstraction over the notion of multiple events firing, you need just that - an event emitter pattern. Promise do not change state once they resolve.

```
function each(promises, progressHandler){
    return $q.all(promises.map(function(promise){
        return promise.then(function(val){ progressHandler(val); return val; }); 
    }));
}
```

This acts like `$q.all` except it notifies you of progress which is not a part of a promise via a minimalistic event emitter like interface. Usage would be

```
 each([p1,p2,p3],function(val){
     // change progress bar width or notify data
 }).then(function(values){
     // here, all promises resolved
 });
```

Note, you can also use `$q`s built in `notify` progress system, but it is my belief, as well as the belief of most people I talk to in the promise community that promise notification is broken, and it is likely to be replaced in the future so I would not rely on it.

Comment: You'll need to return `d`, but I think OP wants to handle the result of all the promises, not just the first one that is fulfilled.

Comment: @ivarni: You're right, I was asking for `each`. But `any` is also interesting and probably good enough. The best thing is that I understand the answer.

Comment: @maaartinus keep in mind that promises resolve once, if you need multiple resolutions - promises are not the right tool - consider an event emitter pattern instead.

Comment: @maaartinus I've added an answer that does that, let me know what you think.

Comment: I'd say, you're cheating... but this way I can have both. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) all you have to work with is `all()` which sounds like its not really what you want. To my knowledge you're going to be stuck with

```
request1(user.name).then(displaySomeData);
request2(user.id).then(displaySomeData);
```

Which I personally prefer over the callback approach.

Comment: I was pointing out that `.all` is all he got if he is using angular's `$q` implementation. But `.any` would surely not cut it either, since he needs to handle the response from both requests?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. This answer is wrong though, it calls the callback twice, and also reverts to callbacks instead of using the promises approach.

Comment: From reading the question I got the feel that OP wants `displaySomeData` to be run for the result of both requests, but I'll agree that the `aggregateRequest` method probably isn't a good idea. I'll remove it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your answer